# no sound on ubuntu and only HDMI shown

Tags: sound, alsa, soundcard

I know this has been asked a million times, but after reaching page 25 on various searches and opening every link on every page, I still couldn't find any solution that worked.
My computer is a Chuwi Geminibook Pro. Until yesterday pavucontrol only had "dummy output" as output device, but now it only has " HDMI/DisplayPort 3 (unplugged)".
Alsamixer only shows S/PDIF, everything is 00. I installed Ubuntu a month ago, and know close to nothing of computers, so please be patient with me.
cat /proc/asound/cards :

```
0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xa1210000 irq 129
```

inxi:

```
CPU: Quad Core Intel Celeron J4125 (-MCP-) speed/min/max: 1166/800/2700 MHz 
Kernel: 5.13.0-39-generic x86_64 Up: 1d 3h 27m 
Mem: 4301.3/7767.1 MiB (55.4%) Storage: 238.47 GiB (10.8% used) Procs: 306 
Shell: bash 5.0.17 inxi: 3.0.38
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Gemini Lake Host Bridge (rev 06)
00:00.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Processor Participant (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 605 (rev 06)
00:0e.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 3198 (rev 06)
00:0f.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Trusted Execution Engine Interface (rev 06)
00:12.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 31e3 (rev 06)
00:14.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Gemini Lake PCI Express Root Port (rev f6)
00:15.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 31a8 (rev 06)
00:16.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO I2C Host Controller (rev 06)
00:16.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO I2C Host Controller (rev 06)
00:16.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31b0 (rev 06)
00:16.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31b2 (rev 06)
00:17.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31b4 (rev 06)
00:17.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31b6 (rev 06)
00:17.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31b8 (rev 06)
00:17.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31ba (rev 06)
00:18.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 06)
00:18.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 06)
00:18.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 06)
00:18.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 06)
00:19.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO SPI Host Controller (rev 06)
00:19.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO SPI Host Controller (rev 06)
00:19.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO SPI Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1c.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor SDA Standard Compliant SD Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Device 31d0 (rev 06)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 31e8 (rev 06)
00:1f.1 SMBus: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Gaussian Mixture Model (rev 06)
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

aplay -l:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I don't know what other things I should show you, please let me know in case
(also, I don't have any external sound device attached (earphones, etc))

Comment: Hello. A good place to start any question is what version of Ubuntu you are using?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 lts focal fossa (I hope that's the answer to your question)